# Please help tune MySQL config

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.3

Anyone can help me to check this MySQL configuration? I have a VPS 2GB RAM - 2 vcpu, installed cyberpanel from litespeed. Any help would be appreciated!

`my.cnf` settings are:

```
[client]
port                        = 3306
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice                        = 0

[mysqld]
tmpdir = /dev/shm
binlog_cache_size = 64K
thread_stack = 256K
max_heap_table_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 256K
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
performance_schema_max_table_instances = 400
performance_schema = ON
innodb_io_capacity = 6000
innodb_io_capacity_max = 10000
table_definition_cache = 400
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 128M
max_allowed_packet = 100G
table_open_cache = 32000
tmp_table_size = 100M
max_heap_table_size = 100M
sort_buffer_size = 768K
net_buffer_length = 4K
read_buffer_size = 768K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
thread_cache_size = 64
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = OFF
sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

#skip-name-resolve
max_connections = 100
max_connect_errors = 100
open_files_limit = 65535

log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=mixed
server-id = 1
expire_logs_days = 10
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 3
#log_queries_not_using_indexes=on

innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1
innodb_log_file_size = 128M
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_read_io_threads = 2
innodb_write_io_threads = 2

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 500M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 32M
sort_buffer_size = 768K
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

**Additional information**

```
>>  MySQLTuner 1.7.13 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials passed on the command line
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.3.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysql/error.log(8K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log exists
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/log/mysql/error.log contains 15 warning(s).
[!!] /var/log/mysql/error.log contains 3 error(s).
[--] 3 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log
[--] 1) 2021-03-05  2:08:56 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2021-03-05  0:21:10 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2021-03-05  0:15:52 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log
[--] 1) 2021-03-05  2:08:42 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2021-03-05  0:21:09 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 8.7M (Tables: 291)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There are 618 basic passwords in the list.

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 3h 31m 52s (99K q [7.844 qps], 3K conn, TX: 190M, RX: 22M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 97% / 3%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Physical Memory     : 1.9G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 1.8G
[--] Other process memory: 380.8M
[--] Total buffers: 1.5G global + 2.5M per thread (100 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 89M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 1.6G (83.55% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 1.8G (94.64% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/99K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 14% (14/100)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.12%  (4/3349)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 33K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 6409
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 54% (10K on disk / 18K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (14 created / 3K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 98% (434 open / 440 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (61/130K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (1K immediate / 1K locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 100.00% (2272 Memory / 2272 Total)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 89.5M
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 2 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.3.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1-log)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (24M used / 134M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/124.0K
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 90.0% (20 cached / 2 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 1.0G/8.7M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 128.0M * 2/1.0G should be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 8 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.94% (2898858 hits/ 2900641 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 56.12% (747 hits/ 1331 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 2078 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[!!] Aria pagecache hit rate: 85.3% (67K cached / 9K reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: OFF
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: OFF
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    tmp_table_size (> 200M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 200M)
```

Comment: max_allowed_packet can never be more than 1G Welcome to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Additional information request. Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; F) complete MySQLTuner report after 24 hrs AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, ulimit -a for a Linux/Unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have not very much data so its probably going remain suitable for a while. No real changes are needed based on what is provided.

Zero slow queries shows it that the `long_query_time` isn't aggressive enough. Set `long_query_time` to a much lower value like 0.5 seconds and ensure look at the slow query log.

Use `log-slow-verbosity=query_plan,explain`

ref: [EXPLAIN in the Slow Query Log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/)

Check the slow query log to see if the recommendation about joins is accurate.